# Trying to light an LED with one Button and have no idea what is wrong

Tags: arduino-mega, led, button

New to Arduino. I am trying to use a single button to light and turn off a single LED. I followed an [online tutorial (youtube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=913&v=IsDzxtaZCoI) and changed the code just a bit. I know it is for two LEDs but I tried it for one. I have no idea why it is not working. I don't see why it doesn't make sense but it just does not work.

Here is the code:

```cpp
float LengthPush = 0; // LengthPush is the amount of time the button has been pressed.

int ShortPush = 100; // 100 ms push. Supposed to turn on the LED.
int LPush = 1000; // 1000 ms push. Supposed to turn it off.

int ButtonPin = 2;
int RLED = 13;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(ButtonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(RLED, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while (digitalRead(ButtonPin) == LOW) {
    delay(100);
    LengthPush = LengthPush + 100;

    Serial.print("ms = ");
    Serial.println(LengthPush);
  }

  if (LengthPush >= LPush) {
    digitalWrite(RLED, LOW);
  } else if (ShortPush <= LengthPush < LPush) {
    digitalWrite(RLED, HIGH);
  }
  LengthPush = 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting compiler errors? If yes, you have to include them into your question. "Doesn't work" is not a good description. I would think, that the else if statement throws an error, because you try to compare 3 values in 1.

Comment: I just got it right!  My mistake was comparing 3 values. I thought i had to specify that the press length had to be more than 100ms, but less than 1000 if I wanted it to turn on. Turns out the compiler already does that. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Also you can remove the semicolons directly after each opening bracket {. Also try to align your code so that each nested { is indented one level according to its nested level.

Comment: I formatted your source code in Question. How do you like it?

Comment: @chrisl I suggest you to write your comment as an answer, so the OP can close the question

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in the else-if-statement, where you try to compare 3 different values. While this doesn't thrown a compiling error in my Arduino IDE, it will probably not do, what you are trying to achieve.

Instead you need to compare `LengthPush` with one value and then with the other. You can even do this inside the same if statement:

```
if(ShortPush <= LengthPush && LengthPush < LPush)
```

The `&&` is the boolean AND operator, which means, that the if statement will be executed, if both statements around it will evaluate as `true`.

---

I'm not sure, what actually happens with your original code, since it doesn't throw a compilation error. It might be (and that's my theory here), that the program will first evaluate `ShortPush <= LengthPush` and then compare the result to `LPush`. Since boolean values evaluate as `0` or `1` in integer calculations, that messes up the whole intent of this. Take the case, that `LengthPush` is really in the required interval. Then the first part will evaluate as `true`, which means `1` as integer. Then this `1` get's compared to `LPush`, which is always higher, so the overall result is true. But the same result comes, when `LengthPush` is smaller than `ShortPush`.